# Java doesnt work if used from gnome

Tags: gnome, ssh, java, virtualization, jre

When I try to install something( which uses InstallAnywhere) from terminal in gnome I got something like that:

```
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH
environment variable.  You must install a VM prior to
running this program.
```

Workaround of that is connecting to `localhost` via `ssh` or switching to console with `ctrl+alt+f[x]` before starting installation.

Calling `java` from command line or `whereis java` shows proper paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and export PATH and other environment variables in `~/.xprofile` script and make java visible to X session. You should relogin to X server afterwards.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path_to_jre/bin"
```

You can also have the same result by modifying `/etc/environment`. You should restart afterwards.

```
PATH="...:/path_to_jre/bin"
```

Check your PATH variable with env command.

```
env | grep PATH
```